# Is there a supported ftps library for python 2.6?

Tags: python, ftp, ftps

I am looking for a  ftps library for python.
I know there is support for TLS/SSL in [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html)
The problem is that i am using python 2.6 and the support is only for version 2.7.

I have tried using M2crypto but it does not work
here is what i have tried. (this is for "**force SSL for user login**" set to true)

```
from M2Crypto import ftpslib
ftp = ftpslib.FTP_TLS()
ftp.connect(host)
ftp.login(username, password)
```

I get error message `530 SSL required`

and if i try (addin `ftp.prot_p()`)

```
from M2Crypto import ftpslib
ftp = ftpslib.FTP_TLS()
ftp.connect(host)
ftp.login(username, password)
ftp.prot_p()
```

i get

> Connected, sending welcome message...
>   220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.43 beta
>   220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
>   220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
>   USER user
>   530 SSL required
>   QUIT
>   221 Goodbye
>   disconnected.

and when setting **force SSL for user login** to false i get

> 230 Logged on
>   PBSZ 0
>   502 Command not implemented for this authentication type
>   QUIT

Answer (score 0):

**PyTransmit is a simple wrapper on top of the ftplib package which provides an object that can be used to make FTP calls to a PyTransmit installation.**

Documentation: http://pytransmit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/